# NoReverseMatch at / - not understanding reason

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a 'edit settings/ view profile page' drop down item in my navbar. The functionality was working prior to being called from the drop down which now throws the NoReverseMatch error as shown below:

Reverse for 'show_profile_page' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['subs/(?P[0-9]+)/profile/\Z']

I am struggling to understand why this error is occuring when I am calling this url in other templates with no issues, but now that I tried putting this in a dropdown, I am getting this. Should I be doing a reverse call in the views.py? Would appreciate any pointers...

**urls.py ** (subs app)

```
from django.urls import path 
from .views import UserRegisterView, UserEditView, PasswordsChangeView, ShowProfilePageView, EditProfilePageView
#from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', UserRegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('edit_profile/', UserEditView.as_view(), name='edit_profile'),
    #path('password/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='registration/change-password.html')),
    path('password/', PasswordsChangeView.as_view(template_name='registration/change-password.html')),
    path('password_success', views.password_success, name="password_success"),
    path('<int:pk>/profile/', ShowProfilePageView.as_view(), name="show_profile_page"),
    path('<int:pk>/edit_profile_page/', EditProfilePageView.as_view(), name="edit_profile_page")
]
```

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from datetime import datetime, date
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
# Create your models here.


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title_tag = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    header_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    #body = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='News')
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='post_user')

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    #return title on admin panel
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField()
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/profile")
    site_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    facebook_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    instagram_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

**views.py** (subs app)

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm, PasswordChangeForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .forms import SignUpForms, EditProfileForm, PasswordUpdateForm
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordChangeView
from nooz2.models import Profile
# Create your views here.


class UserRegisterView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = SignUpForms
    template_name = 'registration/register.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')


class UserEditView(generic.UpdateView):
    form_class = EditProfileForm
    template_name = 'registration/edit_profile.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user


class PasswordsChangeView(PasswordChangeView):
    form_class = PasswordUpdateForm
    #form_class = PasswordChangeForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('password_success')

def password_success(request):
    return render(request, 'registration/password_success.html', {})


class ShowProfilePageView(DetailView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'registration/user_profile.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #users = Profile.objects.all()
        context = super(ShowProfilePageView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        
        page_user = get_object_or_404(Profile, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        
        context["page_user"] = page_user
        return context


class EditProfilePageView(generic.UpdateView):
        model = Profile
        template_name = 'registration/edit_profile_page.html'
        fields = ['bio', 'profile_pic', 'site_url', 'facebook_url', 'instagram_url']
        success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm, PasswordChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms


class SignUpForms(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignUpForms, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'


class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    last_login = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    is_superuser = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check'}))
    is_staff = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check'}))
    is_active = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-check'}))
    date_joined = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'is_superuser', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'date_joined')


class PasswordUpdateForm(PasswordChangeForm):
    old_password = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type':'password'}))
    new_password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type':'password'}))
    new_password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type':'password'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('old_password', 'new_password1', 'new_password2')
```

**navbar.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Nooz</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <!-- Dropdown code for categories -->
          {% if category_menu %}
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              Categories
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <!-- generates list of categories -->
              {% for item in category_menu %}
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'category' item|slugify|title %}">{{ item }}</a></li>
              {% endfor %}
            </ul>
          </li>
          {% endif %}

          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'new_post' %}">Add Post</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'add_category' %}">Add Category</a>
          </li>
          
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">  
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              Profile
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark">
              <li><a class="nav-link dropdown-item" href="{% url 'edit_profile' %}">Settings</a></li>
              <li><a class="nav-link dropdown-item" href="{% url 'show_profile_page' user.profile.id %}">View Profile Page</a></li>
              <li><a class="nav-link dropdown-item" href="{% url 'edit_profile_page' user.profile.id %}">Edit Profile Page</a></li>
              <li><a class="nav-link dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          
        {% else %}
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
          </li>
        {% endif %}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

I tried the following:

1. checked for typos
2. changed urls.py by adding '/' as suffix
3. removed the user.profile.id to see if that was throwing error

Comment: From where the `user.profile.id` comes?

Comment: Based on your error message, it seems likely that `user.profile.id` is passing an empty string rather than an int as the reverse match expects. Could you share your profile model that is linked to User and ensure that it has a valid value? Also regarding your last point, removing `user.profile.id` would still throw an error because an int is expected.

Comment: @shriakhilc added my models.py.

Comment: @SunderamDubey added the models.py

Comment: 0



Note: as I've been messing around I found that if I replace 'user.profile.id' with just an integer for the parameter like this

Show profile page

it will let me go to the page and then will allow me to go to the form and fill it out and everything works, but obviously that won't work as it will send the form contents to whatever id is listed there, not the appropriate id.

Comment: We need forms.py aswell I think

Comment: Also, I can tell you what I think, I think you have a UserProfile model but you aren't creating the users profile when you are registering them :)

Comment: Added forms.py... what is confusing me though is that it was working all just fine in my post_detail.html file and when copy pasting this into my navbar.html... this error started being thrown...

Comment: could it be because i have an app called subs (which has all these .py) and another app called nooz2 that has my models.py with the profile?

Answer (score 0):

Without the `forms.py` i cant give you a code example, but I suspect if you created a `Profile` object in your Admin panel it would solve the issue. If you aren't sure how to register your `Profile` model in the Admin panel then a simple example can be found in the docs here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects

Simply creating a OneToOne relationship does not automatically create the object, and you still need to create the `Profile` object automatically in the background. Or, if there is information that a user must provide to have a `Profile` then the user is taken through an appropriate user journey to ensure they create one before being presented with a page which has a url reverse to their profile page (using a profile I'd which is none)

You can test this by adding a debug verbose in the template

```
<h1>{{ user.profile.id|default:"Does not exist" }}</h1>
```

Somewhere appropriate, and I imagine it will be `None` and also commenting out the url reverses to the users profile.

What is happening in the templatecis that because the profile object does not exist, django gracefully ignores what would normally be raised as a `DoesNotExist` error if you were to try and access the same object in a shell, or some view code for example.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have the following in an admin.py file: admin.site.register(Profile)

Is that what you mean by creating the Profile object?

Comment: I'm under the impression that I can't collect the profile.user.id which is then passing back the empty string. I looked at my models.py and can't see what's wrong...

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, if you got to your admin panel, then find the Profile link, click that and there will be an option to create a new profile. Then link it to your user and it will work. But you need to do the other stuff I said to otherwise you have to do this for every user.